# instalar termcolor en python2 en kali linux sin usar pip

Tags: python-2.7, pip, kali-linux

Quisiera saber si algunos les han pasado que en Kali linux saco el soporte a python2?

Necesito instalar el modulo termcolor con pip install, pero ya no funciona mas el pip con python2 y tampoco funciona apt-get...

Busque por internet, pero no encontre ninguna solucion.  Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

gracias.

Comment: Por probar... intentaste `pip2`? De todas formas, si no tienes soporte para python2, entiendo que tampoco tienes ya un intérprete de python2, no? Y efectivamente el soporte a python2 ha desaparecido hace ya más de un año (y se había venido avisando desde hace más de cinco). Tienes que migrar a Python3.

Comment: Gracias, modifique el codigo para que funcione con python3.